# Migrate from Hibernate to Persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm writing a project using Maven and JPA (not a web app!).

I wrote my annotated entity classes and the CRUD service classes. But now, I am required to use `javax.persistence.EntityManager` instead of `org.hibernate.Session` to perform these CRUD operations.

I'm using Hibernate as JPA provider and I have everything configured on `hibernate.cfg.xml` under resources folder and things are running properly for now.

I know that in order to create `EntityManagerFactory` like

`EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName)`,

then I have to have `persistence.xml` under META-INF but I don't have this xml.

My question is: how do I migrate from Hibernate Sessions to JPA EntityManagers? And what's the equivalent of my hibernate config xml file in persistence config file?

Note: I cannot convert my project to JPA (there's no option).

Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:D:/db/derby/svn;create=true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property> <!-- org.hibernate.context.internal.ManagedSessionContextThreadLocalSessionContext -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

    <mapping class="entity.Pe" />
    <mapping class="entity.Us" />
    <mapping class="entity.Te" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: persistence.xml is very similar to hibernate.cfg.xml. Following this link http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Hibernate-35-Without-Hibernate-Ridding-Your-Code-of-the-Hiberante-API-Calls you can find a very straightforward comparative.

Comment: @RubioRic yes I checked the tutorial but it doesn't explicitly say how to migrate. do i just create a folder META-INF and place under it the equivalent `persistence.xml` and that's it, or what?

Comment: I want to but I cannot because there's no `project-right-click<Convert<Convert to JPA` option

Comment: **Moderator note**: Let's keep comments civil please.

Comment: I think that "just create a folder META-INF and place under it the equivalent persistence.xml" should do the trick. Folder must be declared in a registered source folder for your project, usually is src/main/resources/META-INF. Then you can execute this line: `EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("YourPersistenceUnitNameHere")`

Comment: @RubioRic thanks it worked. please post it as an answer so that I accept it

Comment: @RubioRic however, it worked under main/java not resources

Comment: Ok. Done. As I said, it works if you place `persistence.xml` under a source folder. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`persistence.xml` is very similar to `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Following [this](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Hibernate-35-Without-Hibernate-Ridding-Your-Code-of-the-Hiberante-API-Calls) you can find a very straightforward comparative.

I think that "*just create a folder META-INF and place under it the equivalent persistence.xml*" should do the trick. Folder must be declared in a registered source folder for your project, usually is `src/main/resources/META-INF`.

Then you can execute this line:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf =
     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("YourPersistenceUnitNameHere")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert it to JPA project by creating `META-INF` folder under `src/main/java/` containing `persistence.xml`

The persistence.xml is very similar, here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="persistence-unit-name">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>entity.Pe</class>
        <class>entity.Us</class>
        <class>entity.Te</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby:D:/db/derby/svn;create=true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
            <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class"
                value="org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The reason there's no option project-RightClick < Configure < Convert to JPA is because your version of Eclipse is not Enterprise Edition. Right?

Download the latest version of Eclipse IDE: Eclipse Mars2 J2EE: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/2/eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32-x86_64.zip

Or you can Help < Install New Software; http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna or whatever version you have.

and then select JPA and EE plugins.